# How to add <div> element inside input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#usr").click(function () {
                var divElement = "<div style='color:yellow;'>more text</div>";
                $('#usr').val($('#usr').val() + divElement);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="form-control" id="usr">
</body>
</html>
```

I want to add this div element inside the text box but it get as the string and display.

Is it possible to do this or is there any other way to do this like input. Thank you

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: seriously?? well its funny because i can't even imagine to do that. sorry! but its not possible

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236778/how-to-put-div-inside-input-type-text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938461/how-to-display-div-inside-input-tag

Comment: You should accept any of the answer. If your issue solved.

Comment: Shivam Tyagi's answer solved my issue.Thank you

Comment: @BuddhikaKulathilaka Then please accept that answer by clicking on right symbol. so, it will help to future user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add div inside an input box but you can use `contenteditable` div instead of input field, if you have no such issue  in using that.

And you can add anything inside that.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Answer (score 1):

Putting `div` inside `input`  is not possible .

[Check Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.4)

Answer (score 0):

it will add in input and return object type as output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#usr").click(function(){

    $('#usr').val($(this).html('<div></div>'));
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="form-control" id="usr">
```

Comment: it will return the object so object says it self that is added inside

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#usr").click(function(){
var divElement="<div style='color:yellow;'>more text</div>";
    $('#usr').val($('#usr').val() + divElement);
});
});
```

and when you want to add any html element then use append like below:

```
$('#usr').append($('#usr').val() + divElement);
```

Comment: is this same funtion I put above?

Comment: PLease Compare and Check @Buddhika Kulathilaka

Comment: @javedrathod It will add div inside input?

Comment: yes it will put on click of input , and next time please check code and put your review

Comment: @javedrathod OP doesn't want to display div element  inside input. OP want to add div. Please read question first. https://jsfiddle.net/8sa6n2o3/

Answer (score 0):

You can not put `div` Or **any other element** inside `input`. You can insert simple text inside input.

like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#usr").click(function(){
var divElement="more text";
    $('#usr').val($('#usr').val() + divElement);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="usr">
```